# Не могу понять как реализовать этот алгоритм на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, строки, текст

Есть строка:

```
text = "000jre312"
```

И есть список букв:

```
letters = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a',
           's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'z', 'x', 'c',
           'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', 'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U',
           'I', 'O', 'P', 'A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K',
           'L', 'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M']
```

Мне нужно, чтобы алгоритм проверял, есть ли в строке какая нибудь из этих букв.
Как это сделать без кучи if else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

выводит индексы символов из строки, если такие символы есть в списке `letters`

```
text = "000jre312"
letters = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a',
           's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'z', 'x', 'c',
           'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', 'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U',
           'I', 'O', 'P', 'A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K',
           'L', 'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M']

for index,val in enumerate(text):
    if val in letters:
        print(index)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text = "000jre312"

letters = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a',
           's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'z', 'x', 'c',
           'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', 'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U',
           'I', 'O', 'P', 'A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K',
           'L', 'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M']

result = set(text).intersection(letters)

print('Есть совпадающая буква' if result else 'Нет совпадающих букв')
```

Comment: для проверки очень красиво! а можно так вывести и сами повторяющиеся символы?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin если вывести result, то там и будут буквы, общие для обоих списков. Правда, set не гарантирует, что они выведутся в каком-то определённом порядке (могут быть и не в той последовательности, как в исходном списке). И каждая буква выведется только один раз (даже если в исходном списке она была несколько раз)